# I want all rows of the excel file to be saved as a list. What to do

Tags: python, openpyxl

```
data=[]
workbook=openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='crawling.xlsx')
sheet=workbook.active
for row in sheet.rows:
    data.append(row[0].value)
```

This prints only part. I want to bring the whole. Excel files are only stored in column A.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of lists for each row:

```py
import openpyxl

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='Financial Sample.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.active

data = [[cell.value for cell in row] for row in sheet.rows]

print(data)
```

Output (some sample data):

```
[['Segment', 'Country', 'Product', 'Discount Band', 'Units Sold', 'Manufacturing Price', 'Sale Price', 'Gross Sales', 'Discounts', ' Sales', 'COGS', 'Profit', 'Date', 'Month Number', 'Month Name', 'Year'],
 ['Channel Partners', 'Canada', 'Montana', 'None', 2518, 5, 12, 30216, 0, 30216, 7554, 22662, datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 0, 0), 6, 'June', '2014']]
```

Comment: list(iter_rows(max_col=1, values_only=True))

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly can't you just merge them?